# Does Windows 7 mess with your small tiled background wallpaper?

Tags: windows-7, windows, images, desktop-customization

I have a little pixel-perfect pattern image that I made. It's a 32x32 PNG image intended as a tiled desktop background / wallpaper. I use it on my Mac OS X and Windows Vista installs.

When I use it in Windows 7 as a tiled background, it looks messed up. It's no longer pixel-perfect and looks like it has some kind of filtering or moiré effect going on.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

It probably doesn't 'cut off' extra tiles on the border but rounds count of tiles to screen width/height and then scales it to real screen size.

Creating an image with size of your screen and tiling it in any graphical editor will surely work anyway.

Comment: I'll try that. That's annoying if true - I guess everyone must be all about big distracting photos/images rather than nice patterns these days!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 transcodes the wallpapers before applying them. You could try to add the wallpaper directly in the registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"WallPaper"="X:\\path to your\\wallpaper.bmp"
"WallpaperStyle"="0"
"TileWallpaper"="1"
```